# Search in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

Please help me with the problem below:

I am using `IF(SEARCH('Fashion',A1)1,0)` to search for word Fashion in Column A.
It gives 1 when it finds word fashion but gives error `#VALUE!` when gets words such as 'Lifestyle' and 'Photography'.

Basically containing letters of word 'Fashion'.

Comment: do you check my below answer? is it working your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SEARCH` function returns the position of substring when it's found in text, and the `#VALUE!` error if not. The `ISNUMBER` function returns `TRUE` for numbers and `FALSE` for anything else.

So, if `SEARCH` finds substring, it returns the position as a number, and `ISNUMBER` returns `TRUE`. However, if `SEARCH` doesn't find substring, it returns a `#VALUE!` error, causing `ISNUMBER` to return `FALSE`.

---

**Use following formula**:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Fashion',A1)), 1, 0)
```

---

Reference : [exceljet.net](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text)

---

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `IF` use `IFERROR` as:

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH("Fashion",A1),0)
```